# QueryDsl - subquery in collection expression

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, querydsl

I'm using spring-data-jpa and querydsl (3.2.3)
 I have a scenario where I'm creating set of predicates based on user filer/input. All of these comes to `BooleanExpression`.

My simplified model looks as following:

```
@Entity
public class Invoice {
    @ManyToOne
    private Supplier supplier;
}

@Entity
public class Supplier {
    private String number;
}

@Entity
public class Company {
    private String number;
    private boolean active
}
```

Now, what I'm struggling with is this query:

```
SELECT * FROM Invoice WHERE invoice.supplier.number in (SELECT number from Company where active=true)
```

So basically I need to subquery in `CollectionExpression` like format that will fetch all companies numbers and sets this into in() expression.

My spring-data repositories implements `CustomQueryDslJpaRepository` which in turn extends `JpaRepository` and `QueryDslPredicateExecutor`.
I hope the answer to this is straightforward, but I'm quite new to querydsl and didn't find the solutions so far.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Here is a variant of jaiwo99's answer in a more JPAesque form

```
BooleanExpression exp = invoice.supplier.number.in(new JPASubQuery()
    .from(company)
    .where(company.active.isTrue())
    .list(company.nu‌​mber));
```

Feel free to merge this into the original answer.

Comment: Seems like `JPASubQuery` is no longer available in QueryDSL 4. Converted this answer to: `BooleanExpression exp = invoice.supplier.number.in(JPAExpressions.selectFrom(company)
    .where(company.active.isTrue())
    .select(company.nu‌​mber));`

Comment: @OliverHernandez How to achieve the same for Many to Mant relation?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44830387/how-to-create-predicate-booleanexpression-for-many-to-many-relations-in-jpa

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
QInvoice invoice = QInvoice.invoice;
QCompany company = QCompany.company;

List<Invoice> list = new HibernateQuery(sessionFactory.getCurrentSession())
      .from(invoice).where(
      new HibernateSubQuery().from(invoice, company).where(
              invoice.supplier.number.eq(company.number).and(
              company.active.eq(true))).exists()).list(invoice);
```

Comment: The thing is I'm using a combination of spring-data-jpa and querydsl. I need to construct a querydls Predicate (which can be further combined with other predicates to narrow the search results). I need to fetch all active companies numbers and use it as IN() clause in first query. I was trying th like that, but it no success:
`BooleanExpression exp = invoice.supplier.number.in( company.active.eq(true) )`

Comment: @wiecia if you are using `in()`, make sure you have a collection as parameter, apparently `company.active.eq(true)` doesn't indicate a collection

Comment: @wiecia i will update the query above to match your need

Comment: yes this was just copy paste mistake, thanks, is there a way to express this in predicate/expression way? I mean in my class that creates this predicates I don't have access to HB session/EM (and dont'w want to have) it should be some generic subqery.

Comment: my scenario is that i'm creating a list of predicates:  `List<BooleanExpression> predicates = Lists.newArrayList();` and at the end I'm putting it together to construct the final search query: `return BooleanExpression.allOf(predicates.toArray(new BooleanExpression[predicates.size()]));` this way I'm able to gather all user input and construct final query so i'm searching a way to construct that IN() subqery without need to inject HB session or jpa EM

Comment: @wiecia i'm not sure I have understood what you mean, you can also build your query without subQuery. just use `BooleanExpression.allOf(invoice.supplier.number.eq(company.number).and(
              company.active.eq(true))));` if you have more question, pls specify it

Comment: Seems like it's working with this construction: `BooleanExpression exp = invoice.supplier.number.in(new HibernateSubQuery().from(company).where(company.active.isTrue()).list(company.number));` but here I need to use Hibernate specific constructions. Just wonder if there's sth more generic

Comment: @Jaiwo99 I need to create  a Predicate for Many to Many relations. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44830387/how-to-create-predicate-booleanexpression-for-many-to-many-relations-in-jpa
Can you please have a look here?