# QueryDsl - JPA query on multiple fields of associated entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, querydsl

## A few simple entities:

[image]

## Tech stack

- Hibernate 5.2.10
- QueryDsl (jpa, apt) 4.1.4
- Spring Boot 1.5.6
- Spring Data JPA (So, using repositories)
- Repositories extend `QueryDslPredicateExecutor`

## I want to make a query with this effect:

> Select associated Meetups where **BOTH** of the following are true for MeetupCampaigns:
>     * MeetupCampaign.id = x
>     * MeetupCampaign.approvalStatus = y

#### Importantly, BOTH must be true

I'm able to get results where *either* of the criteria are true, but not able to filter for *both*

## I'm passing a predicate to the `repository.findAll()`

I'm not sure whether to use the `MeetupRepository` or the `MeetupCampaignRepository`

#### This predicate works, when fetching **just** the `MeetupCampaigns`:

```
meetupCampaign.approvalStatus.eq(approvalStatus).and(meetupCampaign.campaign.id.eq(campaignId));
```

#### But fails in the indirection when I try to get the `Meetups`:

```
meetup.meetupCampaigns.any().campaign.id.eq(campaignId).and(meetup.meetupCampaigns.any().approvalStatus.eq(approvalStatus));
```

In this case, I get any `MeetupCampaign` which has *either* condition true.

## Consider this dataset:

```
<!-- Should be selected -->
    <meetup_campaign id="600" meetup_id="500" campaign_id="200" approval_status="ACCEPTED"/>
    <meetup_campaign id="605" meetup_id="504" campaign_id="200" approval_status="ACCEPTED"/>
<!-- Rejected because meetupCampaign status declined -->
    <meetup_campaign id="601" meetup_id="501" campaign_id="200" approval_status="DECLINED"/>
<!-- Rejected because wrong campaign id -->
    <meetup_campaign id="602" meetup_id="500" campaign_id="201" approval_status="ACCEPTED"/>
    <meetup_campaign id="606" meetup_id="501" campaign_id="201" approval_status="ACCEPTED"/>
    <meetup_campaign id="603" meetup_id="502" campaign_id="201" approval_status="ACCEPTED"/>
<!-- Rejected on both counts -->
    <meetup_campaign id="604" meetup_id="503" campaign_id="201" approval_status="DECLINED"/>
```

Note that meetups 500 and 504 should be selected.
**501 is the important one here**. It should NOT be selected, because the two MeetupCampaigns associated with it each fail one of the criteria.

## Can you help me write this query?

## Updates

### (Simplified) Code for the entities:

```
@Entity
public class Meetup {

    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    protected Long id;

    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    @RestResource(exported = false)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "meetup", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<MeetupCampaign> meetupCampaigns = new HashSet<>();

}

@Entity
public class MeetupCampaign {

    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    protected Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Campaign campaign;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Meetup meetup;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private ApprovalStatus approvalStatus;

}

@Entity
public class Campaign {

    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    protected Long id;

}
```

Comment: Can you please post code for `MeetupCampaign` entity? At least the associations with `Meetup` and `Campaign`. Also, you want to select data only for `MeetupCampaign` or for `Meetup` too with a join?

Comment: @lzagkaretos The query should return just `Meetups`. I'm not sure if that answers your question... Also, code added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found an answer here: [QueryDsl - subquery in collection expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21826773/querydsl-subquery-in-collection-expression)

You can use a subquery expression to find all the `meetupCampaigns` with those two properties and then use the `SimpleExpression.in()` to find `meetups` related to those `meetupCampaigns`.

ex.

```
meetup.in(JPAExpressions.select(meetupCampaign.meetup).from(meetupCampaign).where(meetupCampaign.campaign.id.eq(campaignId).and(meetupCampaign.approvalStatus.eq(status))).fetchAll());
```

Comment: Test passed. w00t